# create a product filter in react js

Tags: reactjs

I have this pagination page I have given the codesandbox link below

I am trying to create   page filters
based on the given dropdown select in react js

this is my sandbox code that I have made

https://codesandbox.io/s/weathered-bird-7ppy7?file=/src/App.js

**when I change experience  price  gender I want to show people   with   based on the given range**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a state for the upper and lower experience limits and the gender. And filter the array for the gender and experience.

I have added the working example in [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/white-microservice-k7x9v).

The filters are already applied to the rendered list, so the rendered list is empty. Play around with the filters.

```
//use a state to store the gender, upper Experience and Lower Experience
  const [gender, setGender] = useState();
  const [expUpper, setexpUpper] = useState();
  const [expLower, setexpLower] = useState();

//filter the array for gender and experience
  const filteredData = data.filter((d) => {
    return (
      (d.gender === gender &&
        d.experience >= expLower &&
        d.experience < expUpper) ||
      (d.gender === gender.toLowerCase() &&
        d.experience >= expLower &&
        d.experience < expUpper)
    );
  });

//handle the change in gender and experience
  const handleGenderSelect = (e) => {
    setGender(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleExperienceSelect = (e) => {
    switch (e.target.value) {
      case "0-5":
        setexpLower(0);
        setexpUpper(5);
        break;
      case "5-10":
        setexpLower(5);
        setexpUpper(10);
        break;
      case "10-15":
        setexpLower(10);
        setexpUpper(15);
        break;
      default:
        setexpLower(15);
        setexpUpper(100); //the maximum experience is set to 100 for 15+
    }
    console.log(e.target.value);
  };

/// handle select change
<select style={styles.sel} onChange={handleGenderSelect}>
  <option> Male</option>
  <option> Female</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-ellis-x64y9?file=/src/App.js) to see the working example.
You should handle the change on `select` component:

```
// keep selected gender state
const [gender, setGender] = useState();

//.....

// filter data by gender
const filteredData = data.filter((d) => {
if (gender) {
    return d.gender === gender || d.gender === gender.toLowerCase();
}
    return true;
});

// handle select change
const handleGenderSelect = (e) => {
    setGender(e.target.value);
};

//.....

// handle select change
<select style={styles.sel} onChange={handleGenderSelect}>
  <option> Male</option>
  <option> Female</option>
</select>
```

Comment: how do i show all genders in the initail loading

Comment: here male is selected defultly

Comment: I have updated the answer and sandbox accordingly so that male is not selected by default, the lines `const [gender, setGender] = useState();` and `const filteredData = data.filter((d) => {
    if (gender) {
      return d.gender === gender || d.gender === gender.toLowerCase();
    }
    return true;
  });`

Comment: gender is working can u help me with the rest of the filters too   experice, price

Comment: will u be able to help me sir

Comment: Yes, I will update the sandbox in a while

Comment: oke thanx sir u are a life saver

Comment: I have updated the sandbox, can you please accept my answer by clicking the tick icon next to my answer, if that solves your problem?